# C Loop through a small array and add to a large array

Tags: c, arrays, string, loops

my first time here, im a very novice student in programming and I have a problem I cant find any solution for.
I’m writing a code to do vigenere cipher but I have problems with it:

First: Key is to be entered, let’s say that the key is; “aaa”

Second: Text to be encrypted, let’s say that the text is:”alligator”

The cipher should be:

alligator

+

## aaa|aaa|aaa (key to rerun each extra letter in the text vs key)

a 
+
a 
ciphered first letter;
b

all the text:

bmmjhbups

My problem is how to loop through alligator with the shorter abc? In all my attempts the abc becomes zero when looping pass it instead of starting from the beginning when the loop for the text is passed the length of the abc. 
I have also tried with strcpy and concatenate so that the abc becomes the same strlength at alligator but i meet problems in the strcpy and cat metodes due to strange symbols in the begging of the string.
Do any have a easy solution regarding how a loop can work through a bigger loop ?

Comment: Could you provide some code, so we can better help you out?

Comment: simply use the index of the plaintext modulo keylength as index to the key, e.g. `cypher = plain[i] + key[i % keylength]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I probably shouldn't post this (as no code sample was provided), here's a piece of code that does what you want. However, a couple of ideas:

- According to [Vigenere wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vigen%C3%A8re_cipher), each letter has a number associated with it:

  > - *a* ..  0
  > - *b* ..  1
  > - ...
  > - *z* .. 25

  and  when adding 2 letters their values are added and then the `% 26` (modulo) is applied to the result. E.g. '*a*' + '*a*' = (0 + 0) % 26 = 0 which is also **a** (which is different than **b** that you are expecting), that's why I had to add the `CUSTOM_OFFSET` shifting every result from the table (forward) by 1.
- The cipher works either with upper or lower case letters, not with both (or any other characters). Probably some `text` and `key` validation routines could be added. Anyway in this case, lowercase are used.

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>

#define BASE_CHR 'a'  //Change it to 'A' if working with uppercases (can't have both)
#define ALPHABET_LEN ('z' - 'a' + 1)

#define CUSTOM_OFFSET 1  //According to specs should be 0, but it wouldn't match the current requirements

int main() {
    char *text = "alligator", *key = "aaa", *new_text = NULL;
    size_t text_len = strlen(text), key_len = strlen(key), i = 0;
    if ((new_text = (char*)calloc(text_len + 1, sizeof(char))) == NULL) {
        printf("Malloc error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < text_len; i++)
        new_text[i] = ((text[i] - BASE_CHR + key[i % key_len] - BASE_CHR + CUSTOM_OFFSET) % ALPHABET_LEN) + BASE_CHR;
    printf("Text: %s,  Key: %s,  Crypted: %s\n", text, key, new_text);
    free(new_text);
    new_text = NULL;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> Text: alligator,  Key: aaa,  Crypted: bmmjhbups

Comment: HI, thanks allot for your time and input, much appreciated. You are correct regarding a+a=a. i think there is some good info here for me to use for solving my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at this program. I think it does what you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define NUMLETTERS 26
#define BUFSIZE 4096

char *get_input(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char sign = 1;
    char const plainmsg[] = "Plain text:  ";


    // Convert argument into array of shifts
    char const *const restrict key = "bbb";
    size_t const keylen = strlen(key);
    char shifts[keylen];

    char const *restrict plaintext = NULL;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < keylen; i++) {
        if (!(isalpha(key[i]))) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Invalid key\n");
            return 2;
        }
        char const charcase = (char) (isupper(key[i])) ? 'A' : 'a';
        // If decrypting, shifts will be negative.
        // This line would turn "bacon" into {1, 0, 2, 14, 13}
        shifts[i] = (key[i] - charcase) * sign;
    }

    do {
        fflush(stdout);
        // Print "Plain text: " if encrypting and "Cipher text:  " if
        // decrypting
        printf("%s",  plainmsg);
        plaintext = get_input();
        if (plaintext == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error getting input\n");
            return 4;
        }
    } while (strcmp(plaintext, "") == 0); // Reprompt if entry is empty

    size_t const plainlen = strlen(plaintext);

    char* const restrict ciphertext = calloc(plainlen + 1, sizeof *ciphertext);
    if (ciphertext == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Memory error\n");
        return 5;
    }

    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; i < plainlen; i++) {
        // Skip non-alphabetical characters
        if (!(isalpha(plaintext[i]))) {
            ciphertext[i] = plaintext[i];
            continue;
        }
        // Check case
        char const charcase = (isupper(plaintext[i])) ? 'A' : 'a';
        // Wrapping conversion algorithm
        ciphertext[i] = ((plaintext[i] + shifts[j] - charcase + NUMLETTERS) % NUMLETTERS) + charcase;
        j = (j+1) % keylen;
    }
    ciphertext[plainlen] = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", ciphertext);

    free(ciphertext);
    // Silence warnings about const not being maintained in cast to void*
    free((char*) plaintext);
    return 0;
}
char *get_input(void) {

    char *const restrict buf = malloc(BUFSIZE * sizeof (char));
    if (buf == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    fgets(buf, BUFSIZE, stdin);

    // Get rid of newline
    size_t const len = strlen(buf);
    if (buf[len - 1] == '\n') buf[len - 1] = '\0';

    return buf;
}
```

Test

```
Plain text:  alligator
bmmjhbups
```

However, I think that you might have misunderstood the key, the key `aaa` will leave the plain text unchanged, if I understood correctly, but the key `bbb` will shift the positions one step down in the alphabet. Watch for corner cases such as shifting Z down or shifting A up.

Comment: HI, thanks for your time and input. You are correct regarding the key of aaa = 0.